# Tried to print letter of hindi and strange output

Tags: python

I tried to print letter of hindi using print command and then i see this weird `\xe0\`... stuff. But if i don't use print and print them using just quotes the output works as expected...why so?

This works fine:

```
"This is ऋ ॠ ऌ"
```

However with print it doesn't work fine:

```
var = "This is ऋ ॠ ऌ"
print "Again : %r" % var
```

And I get the output as:

```
Again : This is \xe0\xa4\x8b \xe0\xa5\xa0 \xe0\xa4\x8c'
```

Why so ?

NOTE:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
 # is included
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%r` stands for `repr`, so it's calling `repr()` on your string...

```
>>> class Demo:
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return '(repr called)'
...   def __str__(self):
...     return '(str called)'
... 
>>> d = Demo()
>>> repr(d)
'(repr called)'
>>> str(d)
'(str called)'
>>> '%r %s' % (d, d)
'(repr called) (str called)'
```

... which apparently you don't want. Use `%s` instead:

```
>>> print '%r' % 'ऋ ॠ ऌ'
'\xe0\xa4\x8b \xe0\xa5\xa0 \xe0\xa4\x8c'
>>> print '%s' % 'ऋ ॠ ऌ'
ऋ ॠ ऌ
```